# Teams Bot not responding to user commands

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have created a bot using the App studio and it's working for all of our clients except one. It used to work for them also but suddenly it stopped working for all of their users. They are not receiving any messages back from the Bot. We checked our server logs and we are not receiving any requests from their Microsoft tenant, the same is getting received from other client users who are using the same bot. Is there some setting which their admin user had disabled?  Sideloading for custom apps is enabled for them.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly admin has disabled the app: check -
[Manage app permission policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies)